# Change state to Host down after x hours in icinga2

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

we are monitoring servers with Icinga2. It is not critical for us that a host of a specific host group is down for 5 hours. Is it possible to configure a delay for changing the host down state? It would be perfect if the state changes to warning when the host is down and to critical when the hosti down for 5 hours.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To change the state of a host after 5 hours, you can play with the `max_check_attempts` `check_interval` and `retry_interval` parameters.

In your question you don't specify if you want to be notified after 5 hours or if you want your host change state only after 5 hours.

### notified after 5 hours :

For example, you can edit those paramters to have :

```
max_check_attempts=5
check_interval=1h
retry_interval=1h
```

Like this, when your host is down, icinga will retry each 1 hour (`retry_intervall`) 5 times (`max_check_attempts`). After, 5 hours you will be notified. But in inciga2 console, your host will be screened as down since the first hour (`check_interval`).

### Host down after 5 hours:

In this case, you must specify `check_intervall=5h` and what you want in the others to be notified after 5 hours.